# T-SQL Casting From Nvarchar to Int

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, casting, int, nvarchar

I want to order some data and I need to enter the total number at the end of the table. But the problem is since the name of the total must be total(it is a homework and it has to be identical) I need to cast weeeks as nvarchar. The problem is that when I do that, it does not sort the data properly. How Can I fix this?

```
select CASE GROUPING(Weeks) WHEN 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE Weeks END as Weeks, SUM(Goals) as Total_Goals
from 
(
        SELECT Cast([Week] AS NVARCHAR(50)) as Weeks, SUM([Home Score]) as Goals from Fixture
        group by [Week]
        union
        SELECT Cast([Week] AS NVARCHAR(50)) as Weeks, SUM([Away Score]) as Goals from Fixture 
        group by [Week]

) as tblGoals
group by Weeks with ROLLUP
order by Weeks
```

The Data:

```
 Weeks  Total_Goals
1   33
10  32
11  47
12  29
13  20
14  28
15  37
16  29
17  37
18  32
19  35
2   33
20  33
21  37
22  14
23  43
24  33
25  28
26  32
27  35
28  44
29  43
3   31
30  39
31  43
32  35
33  42
34  37
4   37
5   34
6   39
7   20
8   29
9   33
Total   1153
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you converted weeks to nvarchar, it's being sorted alphabetically, not numerically.

When you order by weeks, convert it back to int.

```
order by cast(Weeks as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

When casting weeks into strings, pad the value to 2 with '0'.

```
select REPLACE(STR(CAST(weeks AS Varchar(2)), 2), SPACE(1), '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will solve your Issue.

Create table #Schedule (Weeks int,  Total_Goals int)

insert into #Schedule values
(1  , 33),
(10  ,32),
(11  ,47),
(12 , 29),
(13 , 20),
(14 , 28),
(15 , 37),
(16 , 29),
(17 , 37),
(18 , 32),
(19 , 35),
(2  , 33),
(20 , 33),
(21 , 37),
(22 , 14),
(23 , 43),
(24 , 33),
(25 , 28),
(26 , 32),
(27 , 35),
(28 , 44),
(29 , 43),
(3  , 31),
(30 , 39),
(31 , 43),
(32 , 35),
(33 , 42),
(34 , 37),
(4  , 37),
(5  , 34),
(6  , 39),
(7  , 20),
(8 ,  29),
(9 ,  33)
--Total   1153

SELECT Isnull(Cast([Weeks] AS NVARCHAR(50)),'Total') as Weeks, SUM(Total_Goals) as Goals from #Schedule
 group by [Weeks] with ROLLUP